# i need a popup window on anchor click

Tags: jquery

Here is my code

```
function Search() {

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "Default2.aspx/BindGrid1",
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $("#GridTable").html("");
        $('#GridTable').append("<tr><td>CRE</td><td>Interested</td></tr>").css('background-color', '#fefefe');
        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {

        $("#GridTable").append("<tr><td>" + data.d[i].CRE + "</td><td><a  rel='GB_show[1100, 550]' style='color:Black' href = 'Default3.aspx'>" + data.d[i].Interested + "</a></td></tr>");
        }

    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert("Error");
    }
    });

    return false;

}
```

When I click on any anchor tag it opens a page *default3.aspx* in the same tab. Please tell how to open it in a popup window?

Comment: Where's your code that shows you attempted a pop up? Have you tried assigning `target="blank"`?

Comment: I don't think the question should have much code like this. Even searching can give you the answer related to the use of `target` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<a  rel='GB_show[1100, 550]' style='color:Black' href = 'Default3.aspx'>" + data.d[i].Interested + "</a>;
```

to

```
<a  rel='GB_show[1100, 550]' style='color:Black' href = 'Default3.aspx' target='blank'>" + data.d[i].Interested + "</a>
```

All i've done is assign the `target` to `blank` - Should get you started in the right area

Comment: when i used target='blank' it open the page in a new tab but what i want is when i click on anchor tag it should open a popup using rel='GB_show[1100, 550]'

Comment: A new tab is a popup; FireFox, chrome etc made windows (that are pop ups) open as new tabs, you maybe should look at loading the page inside a lightbox like fancybox if you want it to be  on top of the page. The code above does what you're asking it to do.